# Move source control from one TFS project to another

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfvc

We're running a TFS 2013 server with several projects within our main collection.

All projects use TFVC for version control.

Is it possible to move (or just copy) the code history completely from one project to another? And if yes, how?

Or do we have to commit the whole code from the old project as new code to the new project, loosing the total history of the old version control? I read something about migrating TFVC to GIT in a new project - but nothing about TFVC to TFVC.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) (Don't let the name throw you...)

This tool can help you copy Work Items and/or Source (with history) between Projects on the same server, different Project Collections or even different servers.

I've used it a number of times and it's gotten the job done (and the price is right... free).

Comment: The ALM Rangers have a white paper on Migrations: http://nakedalm.com/understanding-tfs-migrations-premise-visual-studio-online/

Comment: Does the TFS Integration Platform allow you to migrate the source code within a sub project of a TFS2013 project to another TFS2013 project?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the TFS Integration Platform, with which i have a love-hate-relationship, you can achieve good results with:

- [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/)

There are other commercial options available as well, from which [OpsHub Integration Manager](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/alm-systems/tfs/teamfoundationserver) is probably the most feature complete, but I've ran into bugs with that solution multiple times which required a full restart of the migration or made the migration take weeks instead of hours.

If you want/need a free solution, the TFS Integration Tools can do the trick. If you're lucky it just works. If you're unlucky and the Team Project you're trying to migrate has seen a few TFS upgrades, then it may just run into situations which need to be resolved manually. This manual process is very tedious and the documentation of the steps required are almost none-existent or just too hard to understand.